# How do I determine the name of the active tab and bind it to a property in Angular?

Tags: html, angular, typescript

I have 3 nav-tabs and an active class is binded to the active tab. I would like to read the id of the active tab and set it to a property in typescript.

My variable in the typescript is called `activeTab`.

For example, in my code the id of the first tab is 'nav-home-tab', I'd like to set this string to activeTab property whenever that tab is active and same when other tabs are chosen.

Is there any binding method to read the active class and set property in typescript based on it? I do not want to bind click event because the first tab is active be default without any click event.

```
 <div class="container">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-12 ">
              <nav>
                <div class="nav nav-tabs nav-fill" id="nav-tab" role="tablist">
                  <a class="nav-item nav-link active" id="nav-home-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#nav-home" role="tab" aria-controls="nav-home" aria-selected="true">Home</a>
                  <a class="nav-item nav-link" id="nav-profile-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#nav-profile" role="tab" aria-controls="nav-profile" aria-selected="false">Profile</a>
                  <a class="nav-item nav-link" id="nav-contact-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#nav-contact" role="tab" aria-controls="nav-contact" aria-selected="false">Contact</a>
                  <a class="nav-item nav-link" id="nav-about-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#nav-about" role="tab" aria-controls="nav-about" aria-selected="false">About</a>
                </div>
              </nav>
              <div class="tab-content py-3 px-3 px-sm-0" id="nav-tabContent">
                <div class="tab-pane fade show active" id="nav-home" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="nav-home-tab">
                  Et et consectetur ipsum labore excepteur est proident excepteur ad velit occaecat qui minim occaecat veniam. Fugiat veniam incididunt anim aliqua enim pariatur veniam sunt est aute sit dolor anim. Velit non irure adipisicing aliqua ullamco irure incididunt irure non esse consectetur nostrud minim non minim occaecat. Amet duis do nisi duis veniam non est eiusmod tempor incididunt tempor dolor ipsum in qui sit. Exercitation mollit sit culpa nisi culpa non adipisicing reprehenderit do dolore. Duis reprehenderit occaecat anim ullamco ad duis occaecat ex.
                </div>
                <div class="tab-pane fade" id="nav-profile" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="nav-profile-tab">
                  Et et consectetur ipsum labore excepteur est proident excepteur ad velit occaecat qui minim occaecat veniam. Fugiat veniam incididunt anim aliqua enim pariatur veniam sunt est aute sit dolor anim. Velit non irure adipisicing aliqua ullamco irure incididunt irure non esse consectetur nostrud minim non minim occaecat. Amet duis do nisi duis veniam non est eiusmod tempor incididunt tempor dolor ipsum in qui sit. Exercitation mollit sit culpa nisi culpa non adipisicing reprehenderit do dolore. Duis reprehenderit occaecat anim ullamco ad duis occaecat ex.
                </div>
                <div class="tab-pane fade" id="nav-contact" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="nav-contact-tab">
                  Et et consectetur ipsum labore excepteur est proident excepteur ad velit occaecat qui minim occaecat veniam. Fugiat veniam incididunt anim aliqua enim pariatur veniam sunt est aute sit dolor anim. Velit non irure adipisicing aliqua ullamco irure incididunt irure non esse consectetur nostrud minim non minim occaecat. Amet duis do nisi duis veniam non est eiusmod tempor incididunt tempor dolor ipsum in qui sit. Exercitation mollit sit culpa nisi culpa non adipisicing reprehenderit do dolore. Duis reprehenderit occaecat anim ullamco ad duis occaecat ex.
                </div>
                <div class="tab-pane fade" id="nav-about" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="nav-about-tab">
                  Et et consectetur ipsum labore excepteur est proident excepteur ad velit occaecat qui minim occaecat veniam. Fugiat veniam incididunt anim aliqua enim pariatur veniam sunt est aute sit dolor anim. Velit non irure adipisicing aliqua ullamco irure incididunt irure non esse consectetur nostrud minim non minim occaecat. Amet duis do nisi duis veniam non est eiusmod tempor incididunt tempor dolor ipsum in qui sit. Exercitation mollit sit culpa nisi culpa non adipisicing reprehenderit do dolore. Duis reprehenderit occaecat anim ullamco ad duis occaecat ex.
                </div>
              </div>
            
            </div>
          </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: As u are using bootstrap, I suggest you to use the ng-bootstrap nav component. Refer to the documentation - https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/nav/overview.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should adding the click event to tab item, i don't see any reason it will impact the default active first tab logic.

You can also create a tab component like below:

HTML:

```
<srl-tabs
    [tabs]="tabs"
    [activeTab]="tab"
    (clickTab)="onClickTab($event)"
    (closeTab)="onTabClose($event)">
</srl-tabs>
```

tabs: array of tabs

activeTab: the active tab

clickTab: Output, handle active tab to current clicked one

closeTab: Output, handle recalculate logic of active tab